# How do I find out whether PayPal mobile payment for Android is available for developers from my region?

Tags: android, paypal, in-app-purchase

I'm looking for Google Play's in-app purchase alternative as it is not available for developers from my region. I need to implement an auto-renewing subscription for my app. Is the availability of the PayPal's mobile payment model limited for developers based on their region? If that is the case, where can I see a list of supported countries?

Comment: Leaving your business issues aside, do you have a software development problem with design or coding?

Comment: @Martin James This is the problem I have at the moment.